# how to call flask entrypoint from html in href

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

```
<div class="tnav"> 
    <a class="active" href="index.html">HOME</a> 
    <a href="index.html"></a> 
    <a href="records.html">RECORDS</a> 
</div>
```

now, when i click on RECORDS, i want to call the flask entry point which retrieves all records from database and then shows it in records.html. the main issue i am facing is figuring the standard procedure to handle this sort of scenario? please suggest me suitable way.

thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<div>
    <a class="active" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">HOME</a> |
    <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">/</a> |
    <a href="{{ url_for('records') }}">RECORDS</a>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Then, in your py file:

```
@app.route('/records')
def records():
    # query database and return to the records.html template.
    template_context = {
        'records_from_database': records from query
    }
    render_template('records.html', **template_context )
```

Comment: thanks a lot, helped very much, wanted to know the standard practice employed, got to know, thank you